# Golang channels make program wait indefinitely

Tags: go, channel

I am working on a program with a manager/worker style setup. It has `n` number of workers that get data from an http source, push the data onto a gameData channel, pull url information off of a urlData channel and repeat. I then have one goroutine that is supposed to be parsing the data from the api that pulls from the channel gameData and pushes urls onto urlData channel.

My problem is that the second time either goroutine tried to push something onto one of the channels, the goroutines halt and I have to kill the program.

Here is some of the code and a link to the repo: https://github.com/gaigepr/lolTeams

EDIT:

After reading the comments about using buffered channels, the problem is obviously a deadlock. However, making the channels buffered just makes the deadlock take longer to happen.

At this point is synchronizing the parser and getgames threads the way to go to ensure no deadlocks?

EDIT2:

I refactored the program so that now I am using a threadsafe queue to store the summonerID as well as each worker thread now calls the parser function on its own data. This simplified things in a good way. I did this because I was unable to work around the playerChan eventually filling up because of the nature of the data accumulating. unless someone has a reason not to, I will leave this question open to see if someone has an answer that solves to channel problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me suggest something, you can either use the `default` case e.g.

```
default: 
 continue
```

which helps you handle cases when there are no incoming values from channel(s) you've specified earlier, so you can simply continue your for loop until something comes down the channel, or you could use a timeout case like this:

```
case <-time.After(6 * time.Second):
 continue
```

Of course these 2 cases will allow you to continue cycling through the channels and technically you wont experience a deadlock unless other go-routines stop sending values through the channels.

Comment: That did not solve the issue, it seems the function gets stuck in the loop where it iterates over the slice writing each element
``gameChan <- game``

The other function operates similarly and also gets stuck in a loop of writing to the playerChan. I made a repo, here is a link:

[https://github.com/gaigepr/lolData](https://github.com/gaigepr/lolData)

Comment: I'll have a look at this when I'm home, I'm currently on my phone.

Comment: I've just looked at your solution, I've noticed that you're using the timeout case after some time and I had no deadlocks whatsoever. Is it working for you now?

Comment: @YasirG. I cloned OP's repo a while ago and I can't figure out where the player channel is being read. So, for me it blocks on the second player push. The output reads "About to push player #####".

Comment: Actually, I do see it now. `GetGames` reads one player, then gets a list of games. Then it loops through the games and pushes them one at a time to the game channel. `ParseGameData` reads one game, then loops through the players and pushes them one at a time to the player channel. There's no buffer on either channel. Hence, deadlock.

Comment: I did try buffering the channels just now. I made the channels the length of the number of keys * 10 (there are 10 players per game and 10 games oer api call). Although this made the program execute longer, it still seems to have deadlocked.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't studied your long code fragment carefully but I suspect that you are pushing to a channel without reading from it, so the channel will fill up and eventually your pushes will start blocking indefinitely.

If you want better help, I suggest posting a simple program (~20 lines) that reproduces the problem so that we can run it for ourselves on http://golang.org.

Comment: I made a shorter example but it does not have the same problem. I am going to use that as to see if I can find the problem with my code.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what you should do.  Eventually you will have two programs that are very similar where one has the problem and the other doesn't, and it will be obvious what the problem is.

Comment: This really should be a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Those two operations may wait for each other and cause the deadlock:

gameChan<-game

playerChan<-summonerID

This can be solved by put a slice (or a link list) into one of those go routines to store the accumulating data. Make channel buffered won’t help because it’s limit by size.

Something like this: http://play.golang.org/p/ZtiPkEoPI6

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the nature of the data I was collecting. Eventually the playerChan would fill up resulting deadlocks. I ended up refactoring and using threadsafe queues which worked out quite nicely.